# Keycloak with load balancer redirects to endless loop

Tags: keycloak

I have 2 keycloak instances, configured standalone-HA. Both of them use the same database. I put a load balancer in front of these servers. I use https with valid SSL certificate.
via load balancer, I can open home page, open the login page. When I enter credentials and try to log in, then it starts endless loop between management console page and back login page (I only see their URLs, the screen is empty).
But when I disable one of those instances I try to log in, everything works fine. after log in, I can enable both instances and still they work fine.

I have set PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true

SSL configuration is correct as I can use the dns name and see my valid certificate.

How can I fix this issue?

P.S. I use Keycloak v9.0.0